# In `tf.estimator`, how to `tf.assign` a variable at end of training (not at every iteration)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using the `tf.estimator` API to train models.

As I understand, the `model_fn` defines the computation graph, which returns a different `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec` according to the `mode`.

In `mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN`, one can specify a `train_op` to be called at each training iteration, which in turns changes `trainable` instances of `tf.Variable`, to optimise a certain loss.

***Let's call the train_op `optimizer`, and the variables `A` and `B`.***

In order to speed up prediction and evaluation, I would like to have an auxiliary *non-trainable* `tf.Variable` Tensor **`C`**, exclusively dependent on the already trained variables. The values of this tensor would thus be exportable. This Tensor does not affect training loss. Let's assume we want:

```
C = tf.Variable(tf.matmul(A,B))
update_op = tf.assign(C, tf.matmul(A,B))
```

- What I tried:

Passing `tf.group(optimizer, update_op)` as `train_op` in the `EstimatorSpec` **works good but slows down training a lot**, since the `train_op` now updates `C` at each iteration.

Because `C` is only needed at eval/predict time, one call of `update_op` at the end of training is enough.

**Is it possible to assign a Variable at the end of training a `tf.estimator.Estimator`?**

Comment: Why do you pass it into the estimator then? Just run update_op once at the end of the training manually.

Comment: The computation graph is defined in the `model_fn`, so it is `update_op`. The `model_fn` is passed as a parameter to the init method of a `tf.estimator.Estimator`. I do not see any trivial way running the `update_op` after call to `estimator.train` has finished. As a reminder, I'm putting the (reference)[https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/custom_estimators] on the Estimator API @ThomasPinetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general a single iteration of the model function is not aware of whether training is going to end after it runs, so I doubt that this can be done straightforwardly. I see two options:

1. If you need the auxiliary variable only after training, you could use `tf.estimator.Estimator.get_variable_value` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_value)) to extract the values of variables `A` and `B` after training as numpy arrays and do your computations to get `C`. However then `C` would not be part of the model.
2. Use a hook (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SessionRunHook)). You can write a hook with an `end` method that will be called at the end of the session (i.e. when training stops). You would probably need to look into how hooks are defined/used -- e.g. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py) you can find implementations of most "basic" hooks already in Tensorflow. A rough skeleton could look something like this:

   ```
   class UpdateHook(SessionRunHook):
       def __init__(update_variable, other_variables):
           self.update_op = tf.assign(update_variable, some_fn(other_variables))

       def end(session):
           session.run(self.update_op)
   ```

   Since the hooks needs access to the variables, you would need to define the hook inside the model function. You can pass such hooks to the training process in the `EstimatorSpec` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec)).

   I haven't tested this! I'm not sure if you can define ops inside a hook. If not, it should hopefully work to define the update op inside the model function and pass that to the hook directly.

Comment: The first solution is not satisfactory as `C` is no longer a tensor in the model. However I tried the second solution and it works as expected! From what I understand `tf.train.SessionRunHook` is an interface for defining session-related hooks. After I created an `UpdateHook`, I passed it as `training_chief_hooks` to `EstimatorSpec`. After the end of training, the Variable was indeed assigned.

Comment: The second solution did not work for me: even though the `end` method was ran at session close, it did not have impact on the values of the variables that were later exported.

Answer (score 0):

Using hook is a solution. 
But note that if you want to change the value of variables, you must not change in the end() function since the results of changing cannot be stored in the checkpoint file. If you change the value in the, for example, after_run function, then the results will be stored in the checkpoint.